# Is it possible to permit all users except anonymous one?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

How can I permit access to URL such that only anonymous one can't get the page?
I'm using Spring security.

```
<intercept-url pattern="/pattern/page.html" access="__WHAT_SHOULD_BE_HERE__"/>
```

Comment: Ah, i see now, use /**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `isAuthenticated` either in xml format or annotation format:

xml spring configuration:

```
 <intercept-url pattern="/pattern/page.html" access="isAuthenticated()" />
```

Annotation:

```
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
```

Comment: Cool, but since what version of spring security this is available to use?

Comment: I now it works with Spring 3.1 but no clue if it works with older versions. Which version are you using?